# How does one hyperlink to a URL that contains an umlaut?

Tags: support, bug

For example: [*Übermensch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbermensch) doesn't seem to work, although there is an attempt at hyperlinking to [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Übermensch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbermensch) there.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There are HTML character codes that can be used that you can look up. Either of below works fine for me (Firefox even converted the first one for me automatically).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbermensch
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%DCbermensch

You can use the [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) at w3schools to get the codes.

[image: html url encoding reference picture]

There's also [bit.ly](https://bitly.com/) or [tinyurl](https://tinyurl.com/) for all other linking issues, but those should be discouraged because most people do not know how to use them safely (people should use the safe preview to prevent being linked to malicious sites).

http://bit.ly/12ZMCw9

Just for the record, in bit.ly, simply at a "+" at the end of the url string to preview it (i.e. http://bit.ly/12ZMCw9+). For tinyurl, use the "preview" subdomain instead of the main site (i.e., http://preview.tinyurl.com/123xyz)

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I had the same problem, but I *refused* to manually change the URL with encoded characters. I'm baffled that umlauts in URLs are still an issue, moreover on a tech-driven site! /rant